# Input-Prompt below UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is there any API on `UINavigationBar` to add an input prompt like the provided one in "Compose New Message" view on Messages.app?

[image: Compose New Message iPhone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not built in anyway. However, there are third party controls available for this, like this one from Cocoa Controls:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/titokenfield

Comment: I'm not very satisfied with the interface of the TITokenField, but the source code have guided me to implement a similar solution myself. Thanks. For others looking at the same issue, I recommend to have a look at this source code too: https://github.com/hohl/MBContactPicker